# Why do I have an error that my constructor is not visible even though my constructor is public

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am working on a project to read a text from a note pad and store its content in a dynamic array, then display the list to the user for him to choose a line, then saving the data related to the chosen region in a binary file, then read the binary file and store its content in a data structure of type “Linked List” and save the content of the data structure into a text file.

I created 3 classes two of them are the dynamic array and the linked list. I want to call the dynamic array in a fourth class but it says that the array is not visible even though I declared it as public, and all of my classes are in the same package.

```
public class Array {
    
    private int length = DEFAULT_LENGTH;
    private int eltsNbr;
    public Country[] c;
    
    public static final int DEFAULT_LENGTH = 4;
    
    
    
        
        
    public Array(int length) {
        this.length = length;
        this.eltsNbr = 0;
        this.c= new Country[DEFAULT_LENGTH];
    }

    public Array() {
        this(DEFAULT_LENGTH);
        }
        
    public Array(Array a) {
        this(a.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.eltsNbr; i++)
            this.c[i] = a.c[i];
        this.eltsNbr = a.eltsNbr;
        }


    public int getLength() {
            return length;
        }


    public void setLength(int length) {
            this.length = length;
        }


    public Country[] getCountries() {
            return c;
        }


    public int getEmptyLength() {
            return this.length - this.eltsNbr;
            }
    
    public String toString() {
        String str = this.eltsNbr+"Countries"+"\n" ;

        if (this.isEmpty())
            return str;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.eltsNbr; i++)
            str += "Country [ "+" CountryName = " + c[i].getCountry() + " " + "code= "+c[i].getCode()+ " " + "region = " + c[i].getRegion() + " " + "population = " + c[i].getPopulation () + "]" + "\n";
        
        return str;
    }
    
        
    public boolean isFull() {
        return this.eltsNbr == this.length;
            }
    
        
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.eltsNbr == 0;
            }
    

    public void extend (int additionalLength) {
        Country[] c1 = new Country[this.length + additionalLength];
            
        for(int i = 0; i < this.eltsNbr; i++)
            c1[i] = this.c[i];
        this.c = c1;
            
        this.length = this.length + additionalLength;
        }
        
    public boolean insertAtPosition(Country value, int pos) {
        if (pos > this.eltsNbr || pos < 0)
            return false;
            
        if (this.isFull())
            this.extend(DEFAULT_LENGTH) ;
            
            
        for (int i = this.eltsNbr; i > pos; i--)
                
            this.c[i] = this.c[i - 1];
            this.c[pos] = value;
            this.eltsNbr++;
            return true;
            }
        
        
    public boolean insertAtHead(Country value) {
        return this.insertAtPosition(value, 0);
            }

        
    public boolean deleteAtPosition(int pos) {
        if (this.isEmpty())
            return false;
            
        if (pos >= this.eltsNbr || pos < 0)
            return false;
            
        for (int i = pos; i < this.eltsNbr - 1; i++)
            this.c[i] = this.c[i + 1];
            this.eltsNbr--;
            return true;
            }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//      

    }

}
```

```
    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        
        Array a1 = new Array();
    }

}
```

This is a screenshot:
[image]

This is the Country class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Country {

    private String country; 
    private String code; 
    private String region;
    private int population;
    
    public static final String DEFAULT_COUNTRY = "Lebanon";
    public static final String DEFAULT_CODE = "LBN" ;
    public static final String DEFAULT_REGION = "Middle East & North Africa";
    public static final int DEFAULT_POPULATION = 6855713;

    
    
    public Country(String country, String code, String region, int population) {
        super();
        this.country = country;
        this.code = code;
        this.region = region;
        this.population = population;
    }

     public Country() {
        this(DEFAULT_COUNTRY, DEFAULT_CODE, DEFAULT_REGION, DEFAULT_POPULATION);
    }
    
     public Country(Country a) {
        this(a.country, a.code, a.region, a.population);
    }
    
    

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }
    
    

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [country=" + country + ", code=" + code + ", region=" + region + ", population=" + population
                + "]";
    }
    
    
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        
    }
}
```

this is the linked list class:

```
    
    class Element{
        Country data;
        Element next;
        Element previous;
        
        Element (Country c){
            data = c;
            next = null;
        }
        
    }
    
    private Element head = null;
    private Element rear = null;
    private int length = 0;
    
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.length == 0;
    }
    
    
    
    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = null;
        this.rear = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }
    
    public LinkedList(LinkedList dList) {
        this();
        
        if(dList.isEmpty())
            return;
        
        Element cur = dList.head;
        Element tmp = new Element(cur.data);
        head = rear = tmp;
        cur = cur.next;
        length++;
        while(cur != null) {
            tmp = new Element(cur.data);
            rear.next = tmp;
            tmp.previous = rear;
            rear = tmp;
            cur = cur.next;
            length++;
        }
    }
    
    
    public int getLength() {
        return this.getLength();
    }
    
    

    public String toString() {
        Element cur = this.head;
        String str = this.length+"Countries"+"\n" ;
        if (this.isEmpty())
            return str;
        while (cur != null) {

            str += "Country " + cur.data.getCountry() + " " + "Code = " + cur.data.getCode()+ " " + "Region " + cur.data.getRegion() + " " + "Population = "+ cur.data.getPopulation() + " | ";
            cur = cur.next;
        }

        return str;
    }
    
    
    public void insertAtHead(Country value) {
        Element tmp = new Element(value);
        
        // case on an empty list
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            head = rear = tmp;
            head.previous = null;
            rear.next = null;
        }else {
        
        //case of a non-empty list
            tmp.next = head;
            head.previous = tmp;
            tmp.previous = null;
            head = tmp;
            
            }
        this.length++;
    }
    
    
    
    public void insertAtRear(Country value) {
        Element tmp = new Element(value);
        
        // case on an empty list
        if(this.isEmpty()) {
            head = rear = tmp;
            head.previous = null;
            rear.next = null;
        }else {
        
        //case of a non-empty list
            tmp.previous = rear;
            rear.next = tmp;
            tmp.next = null;
            rear = tmp;
            
            }
        this.length++;
        
    }
    
    
    public void delete(Country value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.isEmpty())
            return;
        
        //case of deleting the head
        if(this.head.data == value) {
            this.head.next = this.head;
        }
        
        //case of deleting the rear
        if(this.rear.data == value) {
            this.rear.previous = this.rear;
        }
        
        //general case
        while(cur != null && cur.data != value) {
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        
        cur.previous.next = cur.next;
        cur.next.previous = cur.previous;
        
    }
    
    public void deleteAllElements() {
        this.length = 0;
        this.head = null;
        this.rear = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not annoyed, no worries. Now you should state clearly what line / statement causes what error exactly!

Comment: @luk2302 In the second code i'm getting an error saying the array is not visible. the second code in another class.

Comment: Could you please add a screen shot of your project structure along with complete source code. Please don't forget to add the import statements  and package names while you 
 are posting .Because according to your given source code , I don't see any error.

Comment: No no no. Don't post screen shots of errors. Post the text of the error! But from the screenshot it's pretty obvious you aren't using the `Array` you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have imported an incorrect class.
Please look at your import statement in the class Testing.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
```

please remove that import statement.Then you are good to go.